# SharePoint Team Site Screen Renders?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

I want to make sure what ever I do on my screen renders correctly for others i.e. my screen is 23inch 1080p want make sure anyone who uses 27in 1440p or 4 etc the page renders correctly. Is there way to page rendering according to screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for sure, this is a common requirement of responsive styling. You should be using media queries in your stylesheet to detect different resolutions / devices. Here is how you would load a specific style sheet based on the user's resolution.

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />

<!-- CSS media query within a stylesheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Answer (score 1):

The above description meant the **Responsive Design**.

There is a good video in Chanel 9 that Learn [how to build a fast, responsive SharePoint portal in SharePoint Online](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2016/BRK3026)

Meanwhile, you can enable Modern site that provides you responsive experience for more details check [Customizing the "modern" experiences in SharePoint Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Also, there is a Responsive UI package that can be installed to make SharePoint Online responsive. at

- [SharePoint 2013/2016/Online Responsive UI](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive)
- [OfficeDevPnP.PartnerPack.SiteProvisioning/Templates/Responsive/](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Partner-Pack/tree/master/OfficeDevPnP.PartnerPack.SiteProvisioning/OfficeDevPnP.PartnerPack.SiteProvisioning/Templates/Responsive)